# Passing data in a class to a function in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to pass the value of a public string to another class that holds a function that runs a command when I push my button on my wpf application. The code is:

```
class SearchViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _SearchValue;
    public string SearchValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _SearchValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _SearchValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("SearchValue");
        }
    }

    public LaptopAsset Laptop { get; } = new LaptopAsset();

    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater(Laptop, SearchValue);
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems _SearchValue or SearchValue is never passed from the bound WPF control:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="276,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SearchValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Even when the textblock beneath it has been set up to see the same value:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="276,156,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SearchValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

So when I type a value in and press tab, it updates the textblock. However the value will not pass to the mUpdater when I push my button. I have code set up to MessageBox.Show the value of the passed string. It just shows an empty message box (indicating a null value).

Why wouldn't it pass across? The updater code looks like this:

```
public string SV;
private readonly LaptopAsset laptop;

public Updater(LaptopAsset laptop, string sv)
{
    this.laptop = laptop;
    this.SV = sv;
}
```

The Grid DataContext is set as follows:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:SearchViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateCommand getter is called by the view after you attach the DataContext/ViewModel (SearchViewModel). In that moment SearchValue is, of course, still null, so the Updater.SV is set to null too.

Instead, since Updater implements ICommand, you can change your View to add a CommandParameter to the Button:

```
Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SearchValue}"
```

and then, inside the Updater's Execute method, the parameter object will be the SearchValue string.

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    string searchString = (string)parameter;
    // do something ...
}
```

Try it out and let me know!

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thoroughly explained and code provided too! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `Button` executes the `ICommand` `UpdateCommand`.

`string` is a value type, so when you initialize `mUpdater`, it will have the current value of `SearchValue` passed in, which will not change in `mUpdater` after it changes in `SearchViewModel`.

You will probably need to change the design in some way - is it possible for you to pass `SearchValue` as a `CommandParameter` in your `Button` XAML?

Other options based on your current design would be to change the `SV` value in `mUpdater` whenever `SearchValue` is set in `SearchViewModel`, or to pass in a reference type of some sort.